# Save position of mouse GLFW

Tags: opengl, glfw

I have my 2 glfwSet functions:

```
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursor_pos_callback);
glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseButtonCallback);
```

cursor_pos_callback functions:

```
static void cursor_pos_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos) {

    if (mouseButtonLeftDown) {
      cout << "y pos: " << ypos;
      cout << "x pos: " << xpos << endl;
   }
}
```

mouseButtonCallback function:

```
 void mouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow* _window, int button, int action, int mods)
 {
    switch (button)
    {
       case GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
       if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
      {
          cout << "Mouse left input working" << endl; //testing
          mouseButtonLeftDown = true;

       }
      else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
     {
         mouseButtonLeftDown = false;
      }
   }
 }
```

I'm getting my x and y output only after I have clicked and moved my cursor.

The desired behavior that I'm trying to accomplish is to just click on my screen an save  the position of my cursor. Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: What behavior do you observe? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: Sorry, thought I was clear about that. I said "I'm getting my x and y output only after I have clicked and moved my cursor". I'm trying to get the coordinate ONLY at the place where I clicked (so a one time event - not a repetitive one like my code does )

Answer (score 1):

The `cursor_pos_callback` is only called when the mouse is moved, same as how button callbacks are called only when a button is used. This is why you're getting the position of the mouse printed only when you hold down the left mouse button and move the mouse.

From what I can tell, you want it to print out the position of the mouse when you click. To do this, you'll need to save the mouse `xpos` and `ypos` in some external variables in your `cursor_pos_callback`, and then print those external variables in your `mouseButtonCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [glfwGetCursorPos()](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga01d37b6c40133676b9cea60ca1d7c0cc)

Inside your callback function it would look like

```
void mouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow* _window, int button, int action, int mods)
 {
    switch (button)
    {
       case GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
       if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
      {
        double xposition, yposition;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xposition, &yposition);
        std::cout << xposition << "," << yposition << std::endl;
        cout << "Mouse left input working" << endl; //testing
        mouseButtonLeftDown = true;

     }
     else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
     {
        mouseButtonLeftDown = false;
     }
   }
 }
```